# Notepad++ sorting lines without a dot at the end

Tags: notepad++

I want to sort my text file.I want for every line that does not have a dot at the end, to be copied to the former line(with a space).

Example :
I do not

own any of this

or that.

To: 
I do not own any of this or that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(?<!\.)\r\n`
Replace with:    (a space)

That will replace all line break by a space only if it isn't preceded by a dot.

`(?<!\.)` is a negative lookbehind that makes sure we haven't a dot before the line break.

Answer (score 1):

You can also Select the lines you want to join. And press `Ctrl + j`, it will join the lines that you want to merge.

```
I do not
own any of this
or that.
```

- Select these three lines and press Ctrl + j

`I do not own any of this or that.`

- if you want to avoid additional trailing spaces, remove from **`Edit > Blanks Operation > Trim Trailing Spaces`** first.